# Extending fermat's last theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory

**Question**: Is the following claim true?

$$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^m\ne a^m \ \ \ \ \forall n,u,d,a\in\mathbb{N}, \ \ \ \ m\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 4}  $$

I am check upto $[1\le n \le 60,1\le u \le 10,1\le d\le 20,1\le a\le 100,4\le m\le 10]$ without finding a counter example.

*PARI/GP*

```
for(n=1,60,for(u=1,10,for(d=1,20,for(m=4,10,for(a=1,100,if(sum(q=0,u,(n+q*d)^(m))==a^m,print([n,u,d,m,a])))))))
```

Moreover if we put $u=1$ and $m\ge 3$ have no counter example by fermat's last theorem

*Below are lots of counter examples for $ m = 3 $ mention but not found for $ m> 3 $*
[General solution for m=3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3481454/647719)

```
? for(n=1,60,for(u=1,10,for(d=1,20,for(m=3,3,for(a=1,100,if(sum(q=0,u,(n+q*d)^(m))==a^m,print([n,u,d,m,a]))))))) 

[3, 2, 1, 3, 6]
[6, 2, 2, 3, 12]
[9, 2, 3, 3, 18]
[11, 3, 1, 3, 20]
[12, 2, 4, 3, 24]
[15, 2, 5, 3, 30]
[18, 2, 6, 3, 36]
[21, 2, 7, 3, 42]
[22, 3, 2, 3, 40]
[24, 2, 8, 3, 48]
[27, 2, 9, 3, 54]
[30, 2, 10, 3, 60]
[31, 5, 2, 3, 66]
[33, 2, 11, 3, 66]
[33, 3, 3, 3, 60]
[36, 2, 12, 3, 72]
[39, 2, 13, 3, 78]
[42, 2, 14, 3, 84]
[44, 3, 4, 3, 80]
[45, 2, 15, 3, 90]
[48, 2, 16, 3, 96]
[55, 3, 5, 3, 100]
```

---

**Formula**

$$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{m}=\sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{u+1}{i+1}\sum_{j=i}^{m}\binom{m}{j}n^{m-j}d^j\sum_{k=0}^{i}(i-k)^j(-1)^k\binom{i}k $$

Where $n,d\in \mathbb{R}$ and $u,m\in \mathbb{Z^*}$ and $0^0=1$

Proof :  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3476906/647719

---

[**Note**: This question was posted in MSE(17/12/19) and got some upvotes but no answer hence posting in MO](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479623/647719)

Related posts

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3473570/647719