# partial sum of a power number equal to a power number with same power

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can it be shown that there exist least one pair for every positive integer $m$ such that

$$a_1^m+a_2^m+\cdots+a_n^m=b^m$$

Where $a_i,b,m,n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and $a_i\ne a_j $ for $1\le i,j\le n$ and $n>1$

Example:

$$\begin{split}1+2+7&=10\\1^2+2^2+3^2+5^2+19^2 &=20^2\\ 3^3+4^3+5^3&= 6^3\\ 30^4+120^4+272^4+315^4&=353^4\\ 7^5+43^5+57^5+80^5+100^5&=107^5\\
8^6+12^6+30^6+78^6+102^6+138^6+165^6+246^6&=251^6 \end{split}$$

An example for $7$'th powers found by Mark Dodrill:
$$ 127^7 + 258^7 + 266^7 + 413^7 + 430^7 + 439^7 + 525^7  = 568^7$$

An example for $8$'th powers found by Scott Chase:

$$90^8 + 223^8 + 478^8 + 524^8 + 748^8 + 1088^8 + 1190^8 + 1324^8 =  1409^8$$

$9$'th and $10$'th from Jaroslaw Wroblewski:

$$42^9 + 99^9 + 179^9 + 475^9 + 542^9 + 574^9 + 625^9 + 668^9 + 822^9 + 851^9 = 917^9$$

$$62^{10} +115^{10} +172^{10} +245^{10} +295^{10} +533^{10} +689^{10} +927^{10} +1011^{10} +1234^{10} +1603^{10} +1684^{10} = 1772^{10}$$

This question was posted in MSE(27/2/20) got a answer by Robert Israel but without getting proof hence posting in MO [link to MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3562259/647719)

---

*Edit*

**Related problem**

Claim $$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^m\ne a^m \ \ \ \ \forall n,u,d,a\in\mathbb{Z}_+, \ \ \ \ m\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 4}  $$

[In this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349248/149083)

Comment: I take it you are aware of Waring's Problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem and the distinction here is that you insist on distinct summands. I suspect that if you dive into the Waring literature you'll find that's been taken care of.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for your reference it's helpful to better visualise.

Comment: It's not so interesting when $n$ is unbounded. For bounded $n$, see desults at http://euler.free.fr/